# Regex to help me break up Telephone numbers?

Tags: c#, regex

I have been tasked with the impossible, maybe?

I have a table with telephone numbers. But they are manually entered, and very dirty.

Example:

```
0711112399
07 1111 3288
07 1111 4832 NIKKI
0711117929
0711113616X123
0
NULL
1300 111 782
```

.

(Numbers changed to protect the innocent. :))

I need to break these into
CountryCode
AreaCode
Number
Extension

So, `0711112399` would become 
CountryCode = +61 (Because there is no code on this number)
AreaCode = 07
Number = 11112399
Extension = NULL

`11113616X123` would be
Country +61
AreaCode = NULL
Number = 11113616
Extension = 123

Rules are:

Possible area codes:

> 02 03 04 07 08

Is this even possible?

For 07 1111 4832 NIKKI - I will remove Alpha Numerics, unless it's an X between 2 numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
^(00\d{2}|\+\d{2})?(0\d)?([\d ]+)(?:[xX](\d+))?
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32t36). You can see the content of the groups while hovering over the blue highlighted matches.

It will put the country code in Group1, the area code in group 2, the number in group 3 and the extension in group 4. All parts are optional except the number. When a part is not found, the value of the group is not set, you have to put your default values then.

I see a problem for the country code. It is hardcoded here with 2 digits, but I know there are also countries with a 3 digit code. For the countries with a 1 digit code, I am not sure, could be that there is a leading 0 then. But I need this to know when the area code/the number is starting.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say impossible but it will require rigorous testing. But I wouldn't necessarily focus on regular expressions. It may be simpler to implement using other techniques.

This is an ideal case to approach with Test Driven development. Start by listing all the possible cases, write a unit test for each case, and adjust the sanitizer code for the case.

Answer (score 0):

There are dedicated libraries to normalize phone numbers, they're very specialized. But they tend to rely on Regex as well. The Lync Server (Microsoft's voice over ip solution), has a normalization library that relies on regex. Their page contains quite a few samples that will come in handy for you:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413082.aspx

In the end, it's probably easier to build a number of expressions that will normalize to a common format, than trying to create one expression to normalize everything.